# Sort response.products before saving into NSArray so I get fixed index every time

Tags: nsarray, in-app-purchase

I went through Ray's in app purchase tutorial at

I got it working, but I found that the product response from Apple uses NSSet, and so the order is changed each time.

I'm hoping to sort it alphabetically before saving it into an array I can use later.

```
- (void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {

    NSLog(@"Received products results..."); 



   self.products = response.products;
    self.request = nil;    

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:kProductsLoadedNotification object:_products];    
}
```

I'd like to get response.products and sort it before saving it into self.products, that way the index number will be predictable.

Any tips?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not use `[[anNSSet allObjects] copy]`?